# KeePassHttp refuses to be recognised as a plugin

Tags: windows, firefox, keepass

I'm trying to make KeePass run on my Windows 7 machine, I've downloaded and installed KeePass, aim to use it alongside [Passifox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/passifox/)

However, downloading and copying the KeePassHttp executable to the `C:\Program Files (x86)\KeePass Password Safe` folder, however it refuses to show up in the KeePass plugins window.  Please help, I've tried download KeePassHttp using multiple links from github and passifox itself using Firefox and even wget.  Also I've tried pinging `http://localhost:19455` but nothing was found.

Any ideas I'm at a loss.

Comment: Do you still have this problem?

Answer (score 1):

From your directory path:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\KeePass Password Safe
```

it appears that you have downloaded KeePass 1.x - and I from my experience latest version of KeePassHttp does not work with KeePass 1.x

I had the exact same issue - by following the [links](http://keepass.info/), I ended up downloading 1.x, because that was the first link on final download page.

And no matter what I did, the KeePassHttp plugin was not picked up.

Solution was:

- install 1.x
- install 2.x
- drop KeePassHttp.plgx (found [here](https://github.com/pfn/keepasshttp/blob/master/KeePassHttp.plgx) to `C:\Program Files (x86)\KeePass Password Safe 2` (note the 2 in the path) and after that the plugin started working.

Answer (score 0):

Try the Linux DLLs.

From the Passifox page:

> Windows Users: If the PLGX file does not work, it is possible to use the DLL files as mentioned above for Linux and Mac users. The above DLLs are universal binaries and work cross-platform.

Good luck!

Comment: I downloaded the source archive and copied the dll straight from there, the plugin still did not show in the KeePass plugin list, and still can't connect with it Passifox